# UIScrollView with UIButtons 'skipping' when finger drags outside of its superviews bounds

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `scrollView` set up as the `titleView` of a `navigationBar`. The `contentView` of the `scrollView` has 4 buttons in it, all laid out dynamically. The buttons need to cancel with drags and scrolling, so I've subclassed them to `setEnabled:NO` on themselves when `touchesMoved`.

When I try to scroll the scrollView, as soon as I pass over the bounds of the superview (i.e., passing the bottom or top bounds navigationBar), the scrollview 'skips' 8 or 11 pixels, depending on if its the top or the button. It has something to do with the `UIButtons`, because when I just use `UILabels` the problem doesn't persist.

Relevant code:

Scrollview Initialization:

```
    menuWidth = 196;
    rowHeight = 40;
    rowMargin = self.frame.size.height - rowHeight;

    //drop down menu stuff
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, (self.frame.size.height)*choices.count);
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
    scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self layoutMenu];
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
```

Button initialization (-layoutMenu):

```
SKScrollableButton *tempButton;
NSString *text;
for (int i = 0; i < choices.count; i++) {
    text = (NSString*)[choices objectAtIndex:i];
    if (i == 0) {
        text = [text stringByAppendingString:downArrow];
    }
    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(0, i*(rowHeight + rowMargin), menuWidth, rowHeight - 7);

    tempButton = [[SKScrollableButton alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    [tempButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:tempButton];
    [tempButton release];
}
```

No events get called on the buttons when the skipping happens, and only normal-seeming `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate calls happen on the `scrollView`.

I've tested and the skipping definitely happens when passing the bounds of the superview, not the bounds of the `scrollView` itself.

Comment: First thing I'd try toggling is the `contentTouches` `BOOL`s. `canCancelContentTouches` seems a more likely candidate but check `delaysContentTouches` too.

Comment: Also, you may want to check what [others](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/) have already done in this area.

Comment: I've toggled both of those `BOOLs` every which way, no dice. And the draggable button implementation I have (overriding `touchesMoved`) works fine, it's just that the `scrollview` jumps when leaving the superview.